# Roslyn compiler - adding reference I built at runtime with MetadataReference.CreateFromImage tries to load dll from filesystem

Tags: c#, roslyn

TL;DR in the end of question, full details below:

I have two C# scripts I want to build with Roslyn.
First script define some classes and types, the second one uses them.

For simplicity lets say script `Types.cs` define a class named `MyClass`, and script `Actions.cs` do the following:

```cs
MyClass a;
a = new MyClass();
```

I first build `Types.cs` into a stream and create a reference from Image, like this:

```cs
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(ms);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var bytes = ms.ToArray();
    Assembly.Load(bytes);
    References.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromImage(bytes));
}
```

Then when I build the second script I use `References` list with the dynamically built `Types.cs` + other standard stuff I added there (like collections, system, etc):

```cs
string assemblyName = Path.GetRandomFileName();
CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
        assemblyName,
        syntaxTrees: new[] { syntaxTree },
        references: References,
        options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary));

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
     EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(ms);
     // proceed here to invoke methods from the script..
}
```

Now here comes the issue: if `Actions.cs` only have this part:

```cs
MyClass a;
```

It works, meaning it recognize there's an object called MyClass at build time. But as soon as I add:

```cs
a = new MyClass();
```

ie try to actually use the object, it tries to load the dll from filesystem and I get exception on file not found because the dll file doesn't actually exist:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'wfkw0oss.mvj, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

**So my question is - if I build a dll dynamically with Roslyn and add its reference as image, why does it try to load the dll from disk at runtime if I already called Assembly.load()? What else do I need to do to make it recognize the object at runtime without loading a dll from disk?**

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the full stack of the FileNotFoundException? And why are you calling Assembly.Load in the first place? I'm asking because I'm guessing the problem has nothing to do about how you are constructing your metadata reference, but rather that once you're loading the second assembly the .NET loader isn't counting your first assembly.

Comment: @Ronen - were u able to solve this problem ??

Comment: Thank you Ronen,
I was able to use your problem explanation in understanding the dynamic linking of assemblies.